# Magento 2 - Customer address custom attribute option label from value

Tags: magento2, attributes, address, address-attribute, customer-address-attribute

I am using Magento 2.2.8 Enterprise Edition

I have a custom address attribute **area** a dropdown attribute with multiple options.

Now when I am getting value of attribute by using this code, I am getting ID

```
$address->getCustomAttribute('area')->getValue();
```

I just want to get **Label** of the **selected area option**, can anyone tell me How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load eavConfig via dependency Injection.

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
)
{
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}
```

Than you can get the label like this.

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', "attribute_code");
$optionlabel = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($attributeValue);
```

Comment: Thank you Arbab, I will apply this solution. Will get back to you

Comment: worked perfectly